# Silverlight website with SQL Server Compact database

Tags: sql, silverlight, sql-server-ce

I created a Silverlight website with a database in SQL Server Compact Edition a few months ago.

Now, I reinstalled my PC and when I open my project in Visual Studio and press F5 then everything works perfect but if I go to the `.web` folder and open the `.html` page then it doesn't show my data, it only shows my page.

Anyone got any idea why this is?

Comment: Did you deploy the application? Deploy it in IIS and browse the aspx page.

Comment: i deployed to .web. But what do you mean with ISS and i can only open the html from the .web folder.